# Always getting error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized) EKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, aws-iam-authenticator

I am currently playing around with AWS EKS
But I always get `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)` when trying to run `kubectl cluster-info` command.

I have read a lot of AWS documentation and look at lots of similar issues who face the same problem. Unfortunately, none of them resolves my problem.

So, this is what I did

1. install all required packages
2. create a user to access *aws-cli* name `crop-portal`
3. create a role for EKS name `crop-cluster`
4. create EKS cluster via AWS console with the role `crop-cluster` name`crop-cluster`(cluster and role have the same name)
5. run AWS configure for user `crop-portal`
6. run `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name crop-cluster` to update the kube config
7. run `aws sts assume-role --role-arn crop-cluster-arn --role-session-name eks-access`
8. copy *accessKey*, *secreyKey* and *sessionToken* into env variables *AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID*, *AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY* and *AWS_SESSION_TOKEN* accordingly
9. run `aws sts get-caller-indentity` and now the result says it used assume role already

```
{
    "UserId": "AROAXWZGX5HOBZPVGAUKC:botocore-session-1572604810",
    "Account": "529972849116",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::529972849116:assumed-role/crop-cluster/botocore-session-1572604810"
}
```

10. run `kubectl cluster` and always `get error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`

when I run `aws-iam-authenticator token -i crop-cluster`, it gave me the token and
when I run `aws-iam-authenticator verify -t token -i crop-portal`, it also passed

`&{ARN:arn:aws:sts::529972849116:assumed-role/crop-cluster/1572605554603576170 CanonicalARN:arn:aws:iam::529972849116:role/crop-cluster AccountID:529972849116 UserID:AROAXWZGX5HOBZPVGAUKC SessionName:1572605554603576170}`

I don't know what is wrong or what I miss. I try so hard to get it works but I really don't know what to do after this.
Some people suggest creating a cluster with awscli instead of GUI. I tried both methods and none of them work. Either creating with awscli or GUI is the same for me.

Please someone helps :(

Comment: I would start by looking at your awsauth configmap and making sure that there is a mapping specified for that particular arn:   `kubectl describe configmap aws-auth -n kube-system`.   This is the relevant doc you'll want to take a look at:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html

Comment: @RickBaker Cannot. Every `kubectl` command was not authorized. That's why I can't connect the kube at the first time.

Comment: Who did you create the cluster as?  What aws creds were you using at the time?   By default that user should be allowed to access the cluster.  From there you can modify awsauth configmap to add other access permissions.

Comment: @RickBaker I created the cluster with the role `crop-cluster` and my aws credentials user is `crop-portal`. So, when calling Kube, I created the assumerole. I assume the user `crop-portal` as the role `crop-cluster` but it did not work.

Comment: Dam I'm hitting the very same issue. Did you manage to solve this in the end?

Comment: @W.Phromma If you created as the role crop-cluster, initially you'll need to have your aws credentials set the same.   Not sure if you initially created it by assuming that role or not, but you'll need use those exact same creds.
From their docs. When you create an Amazon EKS cluster, the IAM entity user or role, such as a federated user that creates the cluster, is automatically granted system:masters permissions in the cluster's RBAC configuration.   Once you have access, then you can edit the awsauth configmap to grant other permissions

Answer (score 0):

I will try to add some more information here and I hope it will be more helpful while setting up the access to the EKS cluster.

When we create the EKS cluster by any method via CloudFormation/CLI/EKSCTL the IAM role/user who created the cluster will automatically binded to the default kubernetes RBAC API group "system:masters" (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#user-facing-roles) and in this way creator of the cluster will get the admin access to the cluster.

To verify the role or user for the EKS cluster we can search for the CreateCluster Api call on cloudtrail and it will tell us the creator of the cluster.

Now generally if we use role to create the cluster as you did (For example "crop-cluster"). We have to make sure that we are assuming this role before making any api calls using kubectl and the easiest way to do this is set this role in the kubeconfig file. And we can easily do this by running the below command from the terminal.

```
aws eks --region region-code update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name --role-arn crop-cluster-arn
```

Now if we will run the above command then it will set the role with -r flag in the kube config file so in that way we are telling the aws/aws-iam-authenticator that before making any api call it should first assume the role and in this way WE DON'T HAVE TO ASSUME THE ROLE MANUALLY via cli using "aws sts assume-role --role-arn crop-cluster-arn --role-session-name eks-access".

Once kubeconfig file is set properly make sure that CLI is configured properly wit h the IAM user credentials "crop-portal". And we can confirm this by running the `"aws sts get-caller-identity"` command and output should show us the user ARN in the "Arn" section like below.

```
   $ aws sts get-caller-identity
   { 
        "Account": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "UserId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:user/crop-portal"
    }
```

Once that is done you should be directly able to make kubectl command without any issue.

Note: I have assumed that user "crop-portal" does have enogh permission to assume the role "crop-cluster"

Note:
For more details we can also refer to answer on this question [Getting error "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Access denied" after setting up EKS cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863539/getting-error-an-error-occurred-accessdenied-when-calling-the-assumerole-oper/60794850#60794850)